# How good is underscore.js at providing truly random numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I need truly random integer numbers in node.js.

I was wondering if anyone had experience with how good or bad underscore.js is for providing "randomness" (e.g. with the _.random(min, max) function) ?

Reference: http://underscorejs.org/#random

Thanks

Comment: How do _you_ define "good" or "bad" randomness?

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-134

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need a truly random number?

Comment: Math.random() is pretty bad psudo-random for most purposes there are better psudo-random algorithms implemented in JS such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/mersenne-twister

Comment: Brad - it's for transposing numbers logged out from an input sensor for drawing onto a graph.

Comment: @generalhenry - that looks like some serious mathematics and was the sort of thing I was after. Thank you!

Comment: Which is exactly the kind of thing I needed it for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dogstatsy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I need truly random integer

No pseudo-random number generator will be able to provide you a truly random number.  For that, you need something in nature.

Check out http://www.random.org/clients/http/.  They use atmospheric noise to get random numbers as random as you can get.

Comment: Ha good point Brad.

OK, as random as a programmatic generator can get!

Comment: random.org looks cool, thanks @Brad. I will consider using this depending on the amount of network resources available.

Comment: Also along those kinds of lines there are JS libs that try tricks like tracking mouse movement to generate pretty good keys.  (or even listening to the mic, but that requires a permission dialog)

Comment: It's a good point, basing the random number generator on some other input.

I considered using timestamps and modulus but then thought someone must have looked into all this random work already!

Comment: @HenryHeleine Psuedo-random generators often use timestamps for seeding.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, `_.random` is pseudo-random, relying on `Math.random()`.  It is not cryptographically-strong and in most implementations predictable.

You probably want to use `crypto.randomBytes`.  It calls down to OpenSSL's `RAND_bytes` (unless you built node.js yourself against a different SSL engine), which guarantees cryptographically-strong pseudo-random numbers, which is almost certainly good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can see from [the annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html), that the underlying function is Math.random(), so the implantation is only as good as the JavaScript engine's implemention:

```
random = function(min, max) {
    if (max == null) {
      max = min;
      min = 0;
    }
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
  };
```

Comment: I only discovered that just now. Thanks @rbp.

Comment: Ha, I'm afraid I don't know how good the default JavaScript engine's Math.random() is for randomness either.

Answers suggesting alternative random number generators are helpful in solving any potential issues with my situation.